# Xubuntu 14 Nvidia drivers problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, xorg

I have a Nvidia Geforce GT740m on my Dell vostro 5470.

I've been having troubles with graphic drivers. When I use software&updates to seek for additional drivers it'll give me several selections, but only the x-org nouveau driver work properly. I've tried different drivers from nvidia, but I ended up with touchpad freeze or last time I couldn't even boot into graphical environment after applying Nvidia drivers and had to uninstall Nvidia to get my Xubuntu working again.

It said that system encountered a problem and do I want to report it. In details it said something about x-org file in system folder.

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. Is there a way I could get Nvidia drivers working on my computer? I wouldn't want my computer to crash during an important lecture or something... I want it to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

I had previous versions of drivers working w/ xubuntu but installed the latest relevant nvidia proprietaries (not a particularly simple task) and found that they had only partially installed. Graphics were fine before & after but when I went to run steam, it wouldn't work. I tried to fix it but it ruined my system & now I'm in [helpdesk hell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544436/steam-error-nvidia-problem-fix-cant-open-xubuntu). So my advice would be: until the various problems out there have solutions (broken pipe, nvidia-current, nvidia latest install difficulties, etc), maybe think long & hard whether the nouveau drivers are a genuine problem, or you'd simply like to have the best drivers because why not? If nouveau are doing the job I'd say leave em alone, unless you find a very trustable how to!